# Unable to install Mean Cli on mac

Tags: node.js, npm, mean-stack

I get following exception when I run `sudo npm install -g mean-cli`

```
module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'are-we-there-yet'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.26/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npmlog/log.js:2:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
```

Anyone has faced same issue? I have npm and node installed on my mac and its included in `PATH`